# Is there a file number/size limitation in a vite/react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have a problem when running my app with vite & react and node.js. Vite allows you to run your app with "npm run dev" that I used before without any problem. However, after adding images (~100 image, I already have more than that on the app, and there will be even more when the app will be released) to my app (I'm running an app that show the output of an AI that recognise license plate and assimiled plate and output the image for me to show on the app) I have a problem when trying to launch it that way, it's giving me the following error :

> node:internal/errors:490
> ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
>  
> ^
>
> Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, watch
>  
> at FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:207:21)
>   Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
>
>  
> at FSWatcher._handleError (file:///"path"/my_app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:52133:10)
>
>  
> at NodeFsHandler._boundHandleError (file://"path"/my_app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:50608:43)
>
>  
> at file:///"path"/my_app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:50452:5
>
>  
> at foreach (file:///"path"/my_app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:50356:5)
>
>  
> at fsWatchBroadcast (file:///"path"/my_app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:50451:3)
>
>  
> at FSWatcher. (file:///"path"/my_app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-934dbc7c.js:50500:9)
>
>  
> at FSWatcher.emit (node:events:513:28) 
>     errno: -4094,
>     syscall: 'watch',
>     code: 'UNKNOWN',
>     filename: null
>   }

And when i removed some image, the app ran with no problem. So my question is, is there any limitation in file number or file size in a react/vite app? If yes, what are the method around it?
I have an API to access a local database if that can help.

I tried putting all image file in the react app to display them, but it output an error. I tried to reach them outside of the folder where the "index.html" is located, but from what i understand it's not allowed due to security reasons.

EDIT : I tried on another computer, with mor file, and the error is not happening... Both are on Windows 10. The file for the first computer are not on the local disk, but on a network drive.

Comment: Seems like this would be better placed on the [Node issues list](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues) or the [the Vite issues list](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues), as the error is clearly coming from FSWatcher (through Vite). Nothing to do with React.

Comment: How many images is "a lot"? Can you identify a specific number that triggers the issue?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think I will post something on those too, but reaching here can maybe give me a more precise idea of the problem (like you did) and maybe alternative solution.

Comment: @MikeB It's ranging from 100 to 200 for now, but will be way more on release. I'm going to edit the post to add this information.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.